Build filter combinations with a dataframe
I am trying to build a Monte Carlo simulation over different filters to filter a dataframe and then compute returns with the filtered dataframe. Therefore I have a large dataframe (appr. 3000 columns) and now I want to compute each filter combination (combination of values of the columns) which leads to over 200 entries in the dataframe.
My first approach was to calculate each possible combination of the columns and then compute a group by the unique values of these columns. But this is not possible due to too many combinations (2^3000 - 1 combinations).
Does anyone have another idea of how I can get possible filter combinations for my Monte Carlo simulation?
